# WPF touchScreen ListBox control design

Tags: wpf, listbox, touchscreen

I need to allow the user to select the item in a listbox on mouse down and when the user drags up or down i need to scroll the items in listbox, since the user interacts with the listbox touch touch screen, i want some thing like the ipod behaviour.
User should be able to touch/grab the item and drag it up or down to scroll the listbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the SurfaceListBox control from Surface Toolkit that perfectly fits touch devices.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957351.aspx